# Enforcing compound multiple keys in django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, database-design

I need to enforce a composite key **at the database level**. The composite key is made up of five columns. In django, I can do a pseudo-composite key with:

```
unique_together = ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
```

However, ALL the data being inserted into the table is from a python script outside of django. The script will simply not work if this composite primary key is not enforced (and I don't want to address this issue at a script level).

How would I go about this issue, or is django simply out of the question to accomplish this here?

**Update:** I see from the comments that this **is** enforced at the database level. Is there also a way to get rid of the auto-incrementing primary key here? Note that none of the columns by themselves will ever be unique.

Comment: Why wouldn't the `unique_together` be enforced? It's set at the database-level, so you'll get an `IntegrityError` if you duplicate the combination of fields. All you need to do is catch the exception and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `unique_together` for this.

From the Django docs on [unique together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.unique_together) docs (my emphasis):

> This is a list of lists of fields that must be unique when considered together. It's used in the Django admin **and is enforced at the database level** (i.e., the appropriate UNIQUE statements are included in the CREATE TABLE statement).